# New CALayer.contents does not display until view is resized

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, cgimage

I have a `CALayer` that needs to display frames of video. Every time a frame is rendered (as a `CGImageRef`), this method is called:

```
- (void)displayFrame:(CGImageRef)frame {
    [view layer].contents = (id)frame;
}
```

What's strange is that this, at first, will not display anything. Every time `view` is resized, a new `frame` is displayed, but sticks until `view` is resized again.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is displayFrame: being called on the main thread? If not then I have found that it will not always draw. You can try forcing it to update by using [CATransaction flush] like:

```
- (void)displayFrame:(CGImageRef)frame {
    [view layer].contents = (id)frame;
    [CATransaction flush];
}
```

If that does not work then you might try including the layer construction code to help identify any peculiarities with this layer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. It seemed that `displayFrame:` was not being called on the main thread. Using `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayFrame:) withObject:(id)frame waitUntilDone:NO];` cleared up the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do `[[view layer] setNeedsDisplay]`. The drawing system needs to be informed that updates have been made and the screen needs to be repainted. Resizing a view does this, but it seems that changing a layer's `contents` might not.

Comment: I added `[[view layer] setNeedsDisplay]` after `[view layer].contents = (id)frame` and I still get the same behavior. :(

Comment: Well, crap. Try marking the view as needing display? `[view setNeedsDisplay:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Using `[CATransaction flush];` did the trick for me. I have to figure out what (if any) performance hit I take for displaying text using this approach.